# How to get a specific string value from an Apple System profiler SPHardwareDataType

Tags: bash, mac, regex, grep, awk

I'm using Bash to rename computers en masse using a part of the serial number, which is pretty easy, but my client has requested that the manufacture year of each machine be appended to the end.

There is an address:

```
curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=XXXX
```

Where the `XXXX` represents the last four digits of the serial number. It’s an Apple service that returns a longish XML string with the model number and year in there. I can’t for the life of me get the only 4 digit number in the XML result from the Apple.com query cleaned up and dumped into my var.

I’m trying this, and stumped as to why it returns nothing at all - when I run it alone in a terminal, it simply moves to the next line.

```
curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}' | cut -c 9-` | grep -o '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)'
```

Is it really obvious what I'm doing wrong? Is there maybe just a better, less complicated way to do this?

Comment: Are all commands working on their own? (i.e. is curl works as intended? is awk works as intended? same for cut and grep.

Comment: Try with `-P` option to use PCRE with grep.

Answer (score 2):

So, I discovered what I needed to do, and found out why my one liner wasn't working. I needed to break it down a little further. I was able to finally set the computer's name to a prefix for the client, the last six digits of the serial number (I realize this is a bit arbitrary, but it is what the client wanted) and the year the Macbook or iMac was built using the following. I'm still not sure why my one liner doesn't work, I think it's because there's an uncoupled token somewhere. I was able to do it function by function as Toto kind of suggested:

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Logging
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>/private/var/log/"$(basename $0)"_"$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")".log 2>&1

# Variables
theSerial=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}' | cut -c 7-)
theModel=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Model Name:' | awk -F': ' '{print $2;}')
lastFour=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}' | cut -c 9-)
theYear=$(curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=$lastFour | grep -o '\d\d\d\d')

#XXX is a client code slug
# Begin script
echo "Begin script: $(theNow)"

# Write: ComputerName, HostName, LocalHostName, NetBIOS
touch /private/var/log/fv2.log

    scutil --set ComputerName "XXX-$theSerial-$theYear" #XXX is a client code slug
    scutil --set HostName "XXX-$theSerial-$theYear"
    scutil --set LocalHostName "XXX-$theSerial-$theYear"
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName "XXX-$theSerial-$theYear"
    echo "XXX-" > /private/var/log/fv2.log


# Finish up
echo "Finish Script: $theNow"
exit 0
```

Two things - 1 - older Apple machines can have serial numbers with a different number of chars. I don't think they will be in the scope of my script's life, so I don't need to count the chars first - then apple may someday stop providing this service, or reformat it adding another 4 digit string to the line of xml, which will break this.

These are acceptable risks for me, but could break this in the future. This is the only way to get the year of manufacture of an Apple Computer into a var at the command line that I know of.

JC

Answer (score 0):

Dropping in my two cents here, another answer for variation. I based my answer off the input above and got the following which runs in less lines of code and works for our needs:

```bsh
# Assign variables to initialize computer name
MODEL=`sysctl hw.model | sed 's/[0-9, ]//g' | cut -c 10-`
YEAR=`curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=JG5J | grep -o '\d\d\d\d' | cut -c 3-`
SERIAL=`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}' | cut -c 7-`

# Change computer name
COMPUTER_NAME=$MODEL$YEAR-$SERIAL
sudo scutil --set ComputerName $COMPUTER_NAME && \
sudo scutil --set HostName $COMPUTER_NAME && \
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName $COMPUTER_NAME && \
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName -string $COMPUTER_NAME
dscacheutil -flushcache # flush the DNS cache for good measure
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!